# Angular get value of a material-list-option within the html file

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this material list:

```
      <mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="onApplicationSelection(14, $event.options)">
        <mat-list-option class="col-md-3" checkboxPosition="before" value="New User">New User</mat-list-option>
        <mat-list-option class="col-md-3" checkboxPosition="before" value="Change to existing user">Change to existing user</mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
```

Immediately below it I need to conditionally display a div based on weather or not the `New User` option has been selected:

```
<div *ngIf(new user option is selected)></div>
```

I know that you can do this in the ts file in various ways. One of them is in the question with `selectChange` but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without having to pass a value to the ts file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <mat-selection-list #selection [multiple]="false">
      <mat-list-option class="col-md-3" checkboxPosition="before" value="New User">New User</mat-list-option>
      <mat-list-option class="col-md-3" checkboxPosition="before" value="Change to existing user">Change to existing user</mat-list-option>
   </mat-selection-list>
            
   <div *ngIf="selection.selectedOptions.selected[0]?.value == 'New User'; else showThis">New User</div>
   <ng-template #showThis>      
      <div>Change to existing user</div>
   </ng-template>
```

Comment: But the user still needs to be able to check both of the options. Otherwise I'd just use a radio button group.

Comment: In your question, you didn't mention it clearly bro.., anyway you have to check it bro.. because it is the condition. even if you use checkbox